# Chrome adds unexpected padding to text input with custom styling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

To put it simply, this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/anf5rL0p/3/) works as expected on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

The input, which has the same styling as the select, should be the same height, but it doesn't on Chrome, how can I fix this?

Upon further inspection, it seems to be related to the overflow property, no idea why though

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.my-custom-forms {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',serif;
}
select.my-custom-forms, input.my-custom-forms{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
    padding: .25rem .1rem .25rem .1rem;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: border .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container m-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="my-custom-forms">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="my-custom-forms">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input placeholder="text" class="my-custom-forms">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap as a barebones, but unsure if it's related to the issue.

Comment: if you look closely the input select for FF and Chrome are not the same...if you dont want to deal with that then just add `align-items: flex-end;`  on that *row* class.

Comment: add height : 33px as well to look same in both browsers - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JzdBzz

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/badvad/7gfx9hjr/1/ try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `overflow: visible !important` for the `<select>` elements defined on the user agent stylesheet. You can't overide this rule with CSS or inline style on the `<select>` element itself.

The following CSS rule is active all the time:

```
select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

If you set the overflow of the `.my-custom-forms` to `visible` (same as the `<select>` element) all controls get the same height.

---

So you can use the following solution (using your current code):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.my-custom-forms {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',serif;
}

select.my-custom-forms, input.my-custom-forms {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.1rem;
  transition: border 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container m-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="my-custom-forms">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="my-custom-forms">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input placeholder="text" class="my-custom-forms">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I also recommend to use the [`.form-row`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-row) and [`.form-control`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-controls) classes on the corresponding elements. Now you can overide the CSS rule `select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple])` so the height of the `<select>` elements isn't calculated and depends on the specified `padding`:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.my-custom-forms {
  font-family: 'Open Sans',serif;
}

select.form-control.my-custom-forms:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
  height: auto !important;
}

select.my-custom-forms, input.my-custom-forms {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.1rem;
  transition: border 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container m-3">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="form-control my-custom-forms">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="form-control my-custom-forms">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input class="form-control my-custom-forms" placeholder="text" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate them.

```
select.my-custom-forms {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
    padding: .25rem .1rem .25rem .1rem;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: border .5s ease;
}

input.my-custom-forms {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
    padding: .25rem .1rem .25rem .1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always tricky to override *user agent styles* and attain a cross-browser solution. As you *are* using Bootstrap 4, where already *that* hard work has been done; you can just *use* them.

You can use `form-control` class which applies these styles *automatically* (you can check by inspecting the elements):

```
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
    height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

So you just need to use `form-control` class to *override* user-agent styles of Chrome & Firefox - see snippet:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container m-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <input placeholder="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```